# Twitter card image doesn't show up

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

I'm trying to create a card for twitter but when I use Twitter Card Validator I get `Unable to render Card preview` with no errors.[image: example]

My meta tags looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Honey Drops NFT Calendar"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="List your NFT drops on Ethereum, Solana, Polygon, Near, BSC. Totally free! Never miss upcoming NFT event, drop or giveaway with Honey Drops."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0itak8f29khy0d/LOGO%201.png"/>

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Honey Drops NFT Calendar"/>
<meta property="twitter:description" content="List your NFT drops on Ethereum, Solana, Polygon, Near, BSC. Totally free! Never miss upcoming NFT event, drop or giveaway with Honey Drops."/>
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5adyp4i59z58o1a/twitter2.png"/>
```

What should I do?

Comment: The link shows a card when you add it to a new Tweet, but there’s no image, I’d guess Dropbox blocks the Twitter card crawler.

Comment: Going to `https://www.dropbox.com/s/5adyp4i59z58o1a/twitter2.png` in my browser does not return an image, but an HTML page.

Comment: Thnks guys. May be you will help, where to store images for this?